# Version mismatch when installing Node.js app

Tags: java, node.js, linux

I have a Node.js application that uses the node "java" dependency.  I did an "npm install" on it, but when I run it, I get the following Module version mismatch error.  I tried doing an "npm cache clean" and removing the node_modules directory.  I did that several times.  I'm running Java 1.7 on Ubuntu.

```
Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 14, got 47.
    at Error (native)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/myapp/java/lib/nodeJavaBridge.js:21:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
"myapp.out" 70L, 3125C
```

package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "java": "0.7.2",
```

Answer (score 0):

Your version of node and npm is too low? (or high, not sure) for that "java" npm package.

Solution: either install another version of node (I recommend installing nvm to manage different node installations) or wait for next release (or fork the module)

package.json for that node-java is  "node": ">=0.10.0" so upgrade node should solve the problem. You can keep the existing node installation by installing a lower version of the node-java `npm view java`

typing `npm view java@0.4.6` shows engine node>0.8 while the next version is already with >0.10